# How to solve the eigendifferential integral for a continuous eigenvalue spectrum?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, quantum-mechanics, eigenfunctions

I don't understand how to solve the following integral in order to obtain the reported solution found in the book "Fundamentals of atomic mechanics" written by Enrico Persico.

The following integral ${\Delta}y$ is named as the **eigendifferential**:

$${\Delta}y\ =\ \int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_0+\Delta\lambda} y_{\lambda}d\lambda$$
where the function $y_{\lambda}$ would be either one of the following **eigenfunction** where $a_{\lambda}$ is constant respect to $x$:

$$y_{\lambda}\ =\ a_{\lambda}e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$

$$y_{\lambda}\ =\ a_{\lambda}e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$

The solution reported in the book is obtained by putting $\lambda=\lambda_0+\epsilon$ and by neglecting the squares of $\epsilon$ which I can't find when I try to solve the integral.

Therefore the solution for the **eigendifferential integral** (where $\lambda$ has been written instead of $\lambda_0$) is:

$$\Delta y\ =\ a_{\lambda}e^{i\sqrt{\lambda+\frac{\Delta \lambda}{2}}x}\frac{\sin{\frac{x\Delta \lambda}{4 \sqrt{\lambda}}}}{\frac{x \Delta \lambda}{4 \sqrt\lambda}} \Delta\lambda$$

It is also stated that the notation $\Delta y$ is used in order to consider the limit where $\Delta \lambda \to 0$ so the interval of **continuous eigenvalues** $(\lambda_0 ,\lambda_0+\Delta \lambda)$ will be infinitesimal.

Unfortunately for me, no step by step solution nor hint are given by the author therefore I can't obtain the result, at least not in the form here given. Any hint or help in the solution process would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two questions: Is $a_\lambda$ a slowly varying function of $\lambda$ around $\lambda_0$? It appears to be assumed. Moreover, are you ***sure*** there is a $\Delta  y$ in the exponent of the last displayed equation?

Comment: I'm still doubtful about the behavior of $a_\lambda$ with respect to $\lambda$, apparently the book gives about it just the information I mentioned in my description so I'm not sure about the possibility to factor out the term from the integral. I understand your point about $a_\lambda$ being a slowly varying function of $\lambda$, that condition would really help in solving the integral. I checked the argument of the exponential and it is correct.

Comment: I think it is possible to solve the integral and obtain the reported solution by using a sort of trick (neglecting the squares of $\epsilon$): $$(\lambda_0+\frac{\epsilon}{2})^2=\lambda_0^2+\lambda_0\epsilon+\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}=\lambda_0(\lambda_0+\epsilon)$$ The integral, by substituting the relation $\lambda=\lambda_0+\epsilon$ and by using the trick, will become:$$a_\lambda\int_{0}^{\Delta\lambda}e^{i\frac{\lambda_0+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}}x}d\epsilon$$ which we can solve to obtain the solution. Still the possibility to factor out $a_\lambda$ has to be assessed.

Comment: Yes, of course that's how the cardinal sign comes up. But you *need* $a_\lambda = a_{\lambda_0} + O(\epsilon^2)$!! That is, you need a stable coefficient.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I just noticed what you meant in the second point about $\Delta y$ in the exponential. Absolutely the term is $\Delta\lambda$ and not $\Delta y$. I will correct it immediately. I checked on the book just for the presence of the $\Delta$ without considering the argument.

Comment: After solving the integral the book gives the value of $a_\lambda$. The steps to obtain the solution are for the most  omitted due to the fact that a long integration process is involved. It is stated that:$$a_\lambda=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi\sqrt{\lambda}}}$$A normalization condition is imposed. I'm grateful for your help and for the insights you gave me.